# Heroku free dyno

Tags: heroku

I have deployed my node app on heroku free web dyno plan.I want to know how much free hours are remaining and how much are left so for that I am using

```
heroku ps -a <AppName>
```

After running above command I got something like this below:

[image]

As per the result everything is clear but what does **Web(Free)** mean written in green color. Someone please let me know any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **It means your app is running on a single web dyno and free dyno type.**

## Dyno configurations

Every dyno belongs to one of the three following configurations:

Web: Web dynos are dynos of the “web” process type that is defined in your Procfile. Only web dynos receive HTTP traffic from the routers.

Worker: Worker dynos can be of any process type declared in your Procfile, other than “web”. Worker dynos are typically used for background jobs, queueing systems, and timed jobs. You can have multiple kinds of worker dynos in your application. For example, one for urgent jobs and another for long-running jobs. For more information, see Worker Dynos, Background Jobs and Queueing.

One-off: One-off dynos are temporary dynos that can run detached, or with their input/output attached to your local terminal. They’re loaded with your latest release. They can be used to handle administrative tasks, such as database migrations and console sessions. They can also be used to run occasional background work, as with Heroku Scheduler. For more information, see One-Off Dynos.

Once a web or worker dyno is started, the dyno formation of your app will change (the number of running dynos of each process type) - and subject to dyno lifecycle, Heroku will continue to maintain that dyno formation until you change it. One-off dynos, on the other hand, are only expected to run a short-lived command and then exit, not affecting your dyno formation.

## [Dyno Types](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types)

Heroku provides a number of different dyno types each with a set of unique properties and performance characteristics. Free, Hobby, Standard and Performance dynos are available in the Common Runtime to all Heroku customers. Private Dynos only run in Private Spaces and are available in Heroku Enterprise.